# JSON Object returned on Http error in Nodejs, fetch

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am using Laravel apis for my project. The API is working fine when I use curl to access it.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz", "filterZip":"123123"}' http://localhost:8080/api/signup {"error":{"message":"User with specified email address already started sign up process, but did not finished it. Please sign in regulary to continue sign up process.","errorCode":"020102"}}
```

However when I call if from nodejs app. I am unable to access the error Json Object from the response.

From Nodejs I am calling my laravel API

```
fetch(API_URI + '/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }).then(checkResponse)
  .then(response => {
    userData = response.data;
    req.session.user = {
      username: userData.displayName || userData.email,
      data: userData,
      auth: authData
    };

    req.session.resession = true; // tell ssrCache to act
    return res.status(200).json(req.session);
  })
  .catch(status,error) => {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
    req.session.user = null;
    req.session.resession = true; // tell ssrCache to act
    return res.status(200).json(req.session);
  });
```

});

```
const checkResponse = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response.json();
    }
  var error = new Error(response);
      error.code = object.error.errorCode;
      throw error;  
}
```

On the Laravel API end following code is used to return response.

```
public function respondError($errorId, $statusCode, $message = 'Unknown') {
        $this->setHttpStatusCode($statusCode);
        $errorCode = ErrorHelper::generateErrorCode($this->controllerErrorId, $this->methodErrorId, $errorId);
        if (API_LOG_ERROR_CODES) { ErrorHelper::logErrorCode($errorCode, $message); }

        return $this->respond([
            'error' => [
                'message' => $message,
                'errorCode' => $errorCode
                ]
        ]);
    }

public function respond($dataForJson, $headers = []) {

        return response()->json($dataForJson, $this->getHttpStatusCode(), $headers);
    }
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: can you post some more code for `node` side, which module you are using to hit api?

Comment: I am using fetch on the node end to call the api. node side code mentioned above. Let me add response handling above

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. 
The issue was with my handling of response. In the response I was not converting the response to response.json() whenever the response.status was greater than 300. once I did that I was able to extract the required json object. Following is a better approach for handling response.

```
const checkResponse = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return response.json();
    }

    return reject(response.status, response.json());
}
```